# ¿Cómo cerrar la sesión desde una pestaña y afectar al resto de las pestañas?

Tags: html, c#, mvc

tengo una duda, suponiendo que tengo un controlador con:

> -Login
> -Index
> -Ventana random
> -LogOff

Y la ventana random se abre en una nueva pestaña por lo que tendríamos dos pestañas (Index y Ventana Random), ¿Cómo puedo hacer que desde la pestaña Ventana random, al presionar el botón cerrar sesión, la pestaña Index vuelva a la pantalla de Login?

Controlador:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Login(string uname, string psw)
    {
        Session["uname"] = uname;
        Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        if(uname == null || psw == null)
        {
            return View("Login");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ConexionSQL sql = new ConexionSQL();
                var usuario = sql.login(uname, psw);
                var existencia = sql.usuarioOCobrador(uname, psw);

                if (existencia[0].usuario == "USUARIO")
                {
                    var caracteres = Convert.ToString(psw);
                    var pruebaUsuario = sql.datos(uname);

                    if (pruebaUsuario[0].clave == caracteres)
                    {
                        if (pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 8 //nada
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 9
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 11
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 12
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 13
                            || pruebaUsuario[0].nivel == 15)
                        {
                            ViewBag.Usu = "Usted no cuenta o no tiene los permisos suficientes para ingresar al sistema. Comuníquese con su Departamento.";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return View("Index", usuario);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Contra = "Contraseña incorrecta.";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Usu = "Usuario incorrecto o usted no tiene los permisos para ingresar al sistema. Comuníquese con su Departamento.";
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
        return View("Login");
    }

    [NoCache]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        Session.Clear();
        Session.RemoveAll();
        Session.Abandon();
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Home");
    }

public class NoCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");

        var cache = GetCache(filterContext);

        cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    protected virtual HttpCachePolicyBase GetCache(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        return filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache;
    }
}
```

En la vista Index tengo este botón:

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" onclick="window.open('VentanaRandom.html')" type="button">Abrir</button>
```

Esto me abre una nueva pestaña con este botón:

```
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ml-auto" method="post" action="@Url.Action("LogOff", "Home")">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Cerrar sesión</button>
        </form>
```

Ahora que tengo las dos pestañas abiertas, ¿Cómo hago para que desde la segunda luego de presionar el botón, la primer pestaña con Index se vaya a la pantalla de Login?

Comment: Puedes crear un método que tras cierto intervalo de tiempo llame al servidor y revise si el usuario está todavía en una sesión válida, si no lo está, que se vaya al index. Otra opción es utilizar una solución como SignalR para que el servidor notifique al navegador, o los clientes conectados, que la sesión se cerró, y así puedas limpiar la sesión y navegar hacia el Login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr cerrar todas las sesiones en las pestañas activas, hice lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.localStorage) {
            $('#btnLog').on('click', function () {
                localStorage.setItem("event-logout", 'logout-' + Math.random());
                window.location = '@Url.Action("LogOff", "Home")';
                return true;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Espero que a alguien más le sirva